# How to exclude certain row pairs with limited number of columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

This data is pulled right now like this:

```
Select * from myTable
```

All the rows should stay except for the first two because they are row pairs that have the same package name, but the second one has a CMPL code. So if there is a package with a FAIL code and it has an accompanying CMPL code row, then they cancel each other out and both should be filtered out. The difficulty is leaving all the other rows with packages that have the FAIL code and only removing that particular pair.

Using a WITH clause I've tried EXISTS, LEAD, LAG and ROWNUM but none of these approaches seem to work as far as I can tell. Somehow there needs to be a way to determine if there are these row pairs for a process where one of the rows is CMPL so that row pair can be removed.

This data set looks different each day. Sometimes there are several row pairs for a package the way I've described. Sometimes there are none. This is a basic example.

Is there a way to determine if one of these row pairs come up and to remove them?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SSMS. Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use except in combination with exists.

```
 
SELECT *
FROM myTable
EXCEPT
/*set of rows you want to exclude*/
SELECT x.*
FROM myTable x
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM myTable Y
  WHERE Y.Package_Name = x.Package_Name
  AND y.Code =‘CMPL’
)
AND x.Code = ‘FAIL’
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The EXCEPT did exactly what I needed.